# отмена потока в android

Tags: android, linux, c, sdl2

я когда делал игру, думал что в android есть отмена потока, но когда появилась ошибка, я посмотрел и не нашел эту функцию. я использовал `pthread_cancel` для отмены потока. Я делаю игру на sdl2 и там используются потоки. как тогда делать? может сделать чтобы один раз поток создавался?

Answer (score 0):

> думал что в android есть отмена потока

В android - точно нет. Android - это операционная система. А *pthread_cancel* - это функция из библиотеки *pthread*. Разница между ОС и библиотекой - понятна?

По сути вопроса. Смотрим man pthread_cancel :

> Функция *pthread_cancel()* посылает нити thread запрос отмены.
>   Отреагирует нити назначения и когда на запрос отмены зависит от двух
>   атрибутов, которые управляют этой нитью: состояние и тип возможности
>   отмены.
>
> **Состояние** отменяемости нити, определённое в pthread_setcancelstate(3), может быть включено (по умолчанию у новых
>   нитей) или выключено. Если отменяемость у нити выключена, то  запрос
>   отменяемости  остаётся  в  очереди  до  тех  пор,  пока нить не
>   включит отменяемость. Если отменяемость у нити включена, то когда
>   произойдёт отмена определяется типом отменяемости.
>
> **Тип** отменяемости нити, определённый в pthread_setcanceltype(3), может быть асинхронным или отложенным (по умолчанию у новых нитей).
>   Асинхронная отменяемость означает, что нить может быть отменена в
>   любое  время  (обычно,  немедленно,  но  система  не  гарантирует 
>   этого).
>
> Отложенная  отменяемость  означает,  что  отмена  будет задержана до
>   тех пор, пока нить не вызовет функцию, являющуюся точкой отмены.
>   Список  функций,  которые  могут  быть  точками отмены, представлен в
>   pthreads(7).

Резюмируя. То, что Вы вызвали *pthread_cancel()*, вовсе НЕ означает, что нить завершиться на самом деле. А если она и завершится, то - неизвестно когда. Обе эти особенности выполнения нити Вы должны отрегулировать самостоятельно, используя упомянутые атрибуты.

Comment: Вообще то android это линукс операционная система. и всё что там есть это системные функции линукса. и так как это линукс, то и pthread должна была быть в полном комплекте. то есть в android есть pthread, и там много функций, но pthread_cancel нет. я уже нашел pthread_kill как возможность уничтожить поток.

Comment: @xverizex "Вообще то android это линукс операционная система" - полностью с Вами согласен. Я только пытаюсь подчеркунуть, что ОС предоставляет системные вызовы. А библиотечные функци (любые) относятся к БИБЛИОТЕКАМ, а не к ОС.

Comment: @xverizex "я уже нашел pthread_kill" - функции pthread_kill и pthread_cancel - работают существенно по разному. Сами решайте, что Вам больше подходит. pthread_kill - просто убивает нить, посылая ей СИГНАЛ, который нить не обрабатывает и просто падает. pthread_cfncel - посылает ЗАПРОС на снятие и нить имеет возможность аккуратно завершиться.